# Is it possible to connecto to a domain socket using Poco::Net::Sockets?

Tags: c++, c++11, poco-libraries

I'm looking at the Poco classes and I've noticed that all sockets require and IP address and a port to connect to. Is there an option I missed to connect to domain sockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you did not miss it. There is no domain socket support in poco. There was [some work done](http://pocoproject.org/blog/?p=210) long time ago but it never made it to the official release.